# auto List with image

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays, search

I have a arralist which contain data like below

```
list[0]= picture name
list[1]=piciture year
list[3]=picture path
list[4]= picture name
list[5]=piciture year
list[6]=picture path      ...............
```

In fact this data come from my webmethod and its sending data every keyup function from textbox.

Well, I need this arraylist  to convert something like div and image under my textbox. and when user click any item than textbox text equal to picture name and something will hide or remove which is the under my textbox by the way I'm using asp.net and I need its javascipt codes or samples.

[image: Here is what i want]

Comment: Have you tried autoComplete plugin with images of JQuery?

Comment: i dont know its. i will try to search.

Comment: im using asp.net AKN

Comment: by the way i look for some plugin about aouto complete. but i coulndt integrates my code.

Comment: im taking data from database as you type to textbox and returned to its inside arraylist. i want to to aouto complete from my arraylist. it will be easy for me. if anyone know easy way ?

Comment: and i convert divided its 3 arraylist like picturename, pictureyear,picturepath



 i want to add autocomplete with images into my textbox. i search a lot of way but i sitll coulnt do its. if anyone help me i will be thankfull.